# Snowflake while loop

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am working on migrating SQL Server stored procedure and loading the data to Snowflake using DBT. I am having some issues with using insert within while loop. Would really appreciate if anyone has feedbacks on this.

Error:

> SQL Compilation error: syntax line 7 position 18 unexpected '('.
> Syntax error line 8 at position 12 unexpected 'insert'.

Temp tables are defined already.

```
execute immediate $$ 
begin 
 set firstmonth = '2022-03-01'; 
 set lastmonth = '2022-04-01'; 
 set currmonth = $firstmonth;
 
 while ($currmonth <$lastmonth) do   
   insert into tmptable( col1, col2)  
   select 1,2 from tableA;
   currmonth = dateadd(month, 1,$currmonth);
 end while;
end;
$$
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax needed is slightly different, fixed:

```sql
execute immediate $$ 
declare
 firstmonth date default '2022-03-01';
 lastmonth date default '2022-04-01';
 currmonth date default firstmonth;

begin 
 while (currmonth < lastmonth) do   
   insert into tmptable( col1, col2)  
   select 1,2 from tableA;
   currmonth := dateadd(month, 1, currmonth);
 end while;
return currmonth;
end;
$$
```

Comment: Thank you Felipe. What if we are selecting dates from a table? eg: 

set firstmonth = (select max(date) from tableA);

Comment: I am also using snowflake worksheets(web interface) to compile my code. before moving onto to DBT.

Comment: Please feel free to ask a new question so the community can look into it (if this answer was useful, please accept it)

Comment: Thank you Felipe. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572189/while-loop-in-snowflake

Answer (score 0):

One way to trasnalte the code is to use [Snowflake Scripting variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html)(`LET`) instead of [session variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html)(`SET`):

```
begin 
 let firstmonth DATE := '2022-03-01'; 
 let lastmonth DATE := '2022-04-01'; 
 let currmonth DATE := :firstmonth;
 
 while (currmonth <lastmonth) do   
   insert into tmptable( col1, col2)  
   select 1,2 from tableA;
   currmonth := dateadd(month, 1,currmonth);
 end while;
end;
```

The assignment operator for Snowflake Scripting is `:=`.

Comment: Thank you Lukasz. If I am to get the dates from a table, how would the code change?

eg: 
set firstmonth = (select max(date) from tableA);

Comment: @ashrayac `let firstmonth := (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableA)` or `SELECT MAX(date) INTO firstmonth FROM tableA`

Comment: I am on the web interface (snowflake worksheet). This throws error.

```
begin
let firstmonth := (select dateadd(month,case when day(current_timestamp())<=10 then -1 else 0 end,dateadd(month,0,date_trunc('month',current_date()))));
 let lastmonth  := (select dateadd(month,1,dateadd(month,case when day(current_timestamp())<=10 then -1 else 0 end,dateadd(month,0,date_trunc('month',current_date())))));
 let currMonth  := firstmonth;
 end;
```