# While loop in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am working on a SQL script below on Snowflake worksheets and getting this error below. Tables are defined. Any feedbacks is appreciated.

Error:

Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 9 at position 4 : SQL compilation error: error line 162 at position 34 invalid identifier 'CURRMONTH'

```
execute immediate $$ 
declare
    firstmonth :=(select dateadd(month,case when day(current_timestamp())<=10 then -1 else 0 end,dateadd(month,0,date_trunc('month',current_date()))));
    lastmonth  :=(select dateadd(month,1,dateadd(month,case when day(current_timestamp())<=10 then -1 else 0 end,dateadd(month,0,date_trunc('month',current_date())))));
    currmonth date default firstmonth;

begin        
 while (currmonth <=lastmonth) do 
    insert into temptable  
    select colA, colB, colC, colD
    from tableA 
    where date between currmonth and dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,1,currmonth))  and date2 = currmonth

 currmonth :=dateadd(month,1,currmonth)
end while;
end;
$$
```

Comment: first check to make sure the column name being referenced exists

Comment: Columns exist. I think the error is in the way currmonth is being referenced in the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, modified the column name from date to date1,

```
create or replace  table temptable  (date1 date,date2 date, colA varchar2, colB varchar2, colC varchar2, colD varchar2);
create or replace  table tableA  (date1 date,date2 date, colA varchar2, colB varchar2, colC varchar2, colD varchar2);


execute immediate $$ 
declare
    firstmonth :=(select dateadd(month,case when day(current_timestamp())<=10 then -1 else 0 end,dateadd(month,0,date_trunc('month',current_date()))));
    lastmonth  :=(select dateadd(month,1,dateadd(month,case when day(current_timestamp())<=10 then -1 else 0 end,dateadd(month,0,date_trunc('month',current_date())))));
    --currmonth date default firstmonth;
    currmonth date ;
begin
 currmonth :=firstmonth;
 while (currmonth <=lastmonth) do 
    insert into temptable (colA, colB, colC, colD)
    select colA, colB, colC, colD
    from tableA 
    where date1 between :currmonth and dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,1,:currmonth))  and date2 = :currmonth;

 currmonth :=dateadd(month,1,currmonth);
end while;
end;
$$
;
```

Comment: referencing as ':currmonth' worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You  are missing semi colon at end of statement.

```
 currmonth :=dateadd(month,1,currmonth);
```

Comment: Thank you. I still get the same error. Is the variable being referenced correctly in the where clause?

Comment: Can you add updated code .. I  also see one more semi colon missing for insert stmt.. Check it.I don't see any issue with variable.